# Unable to boot into Windows10 on Fujitsu Lifebook SH760

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

As a learning project, I set out to restore an approx. 10 year old Fujitsu Lifebook and get them running on Windows 10.

By reusing parts from a number of old units I was able to build a fully functional SH760 which would boot up Windows XP on the original HDD without any issues.

Then installed an SSD with Windows 10 V1903. It will not boot, just has a blinking cursor on the screen.

Research on this issue seemed to indicate it had happened to other users but there didnt appear to be any consensus on how to fix. Below are the things that I tried:

- Different variations of holding power button down for 30 secs
- Removing secure boot options
- Checking the bios for any options to use UEFI instead of Legacy, there didnt appear to be any so I assume it doesnt support UEFI
- Tried cloning the drive from another working W10 device
- One post suggested it could be an incompatibility with later versions of windows, so I did a clean install back to Windows 10 v1703, no change

While it doesn't matter if I cant make it work (having other options), I would like to understand why, if anyone can help me with that?

Comment: At what point after the Windows 10 install did the system stop working? Also, it sounds like a hardware fault.

Comment: @music2myear,  It never worked after the Windows 10 install

Comment: Ok, your question needs to be improved to make it more clear. Please clearly list each step of the process you went through leading up to the problem occurring. Use the EDIT button to add this info to the body of the question.

Comment: Steps taken formatting improved in question